# If $f$ is a differentiable function such that $f(x)=f(-x)$, how can I prove that $f'(0)=0$ using solely the limits definition of differentiability?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Struggling to get to grips with how to go about this question:

"Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $f(x) = f(−x)$ for all $x$. Show, just using the definition of differentiability, that
$f'(0) = 0$."

It is obvious that $f(x)$ cannot be below $0$ given the conditions above, the function will be symmetric (mirrored in $y$-axis).

We know that $f$ is differentiable and therefore that:

$$f'(x) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Would the proof be as simple as substituting $x = 0$ and making $f(x+h) = f(0)$ as $h$ tends to $0$ ?

I appear to be missing some crucial steps here.

Comment: What happens if you differentiate both sides of $f(x)=f(-x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

As $f$ is differentiable, put $x=0$,
$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$$
Let $k=-h$. Then,
$$f'(0)=\lim_{k\to0}\frac{f(-k)-f(0)}{-k}$$
$$f'(0)=-\lim_{k\to0}\frac{f(k)-f(0)}{k}=-f'(0)$$

Thus,
$$f'(0)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, note that if $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$ exists, then it equals $\lim_{x \to 0} g(-x)$. This is because the image of $g(x)$ and $g(-x)$ is the same in the interval $(-\delta, \delta)$. Hence

$$L = f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{-x} = -L \Longrightarrow L =0$$

Answer (score 0):

$$f'(-x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{f(-x+h)-f(-x)}{h}\right)=\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{h}\right)=-\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{-h}\right)=-f'(x)$$
It should be clear from the definition of the limit that taking the limit as h goes to zero or as -h goes to zero is the same thing.